# Create picture module responsive styles programmatically

Tags: 7, media

I could not find any documentation anywhere on how to programmatically create a new picture module responsive style set so am adding what I've discovered here.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to create the image styles:

```
// 1. Create image styles
$multipliers = array(
  '1x' => 1,
  '1_5x' => 1.5,
  '2x' => 2,
);
foreach($multipliers as $label => $multiplier) {
  $style = image_style_save(array('name' => 'tile_image_' . $label));
  $effect = array(
    'name' => 'image_scale_and_crop',
    'data' => array(
      'width' => 390 * $multiplier,
      'height' => 194 * $multiplier,
      'upscale' => TRUE,
    ),
    'isid' => $style['isid'],
  );
  image_effect_save($effect);
}
```

Then create a group for the image styles:

```
// 2. Create image group
$new_group = breakpoints_breakpoint_group_empty_object();
$new_group->machine_name = 'tile_image';
$new_group->name = 'Tile image group';
$new_group->type = BREAKPOINTS_SOURCE_TYPE_CUSTOM;
$new_group->breakpoints = array('breakpoints.theme.armi_embl_theme.desktop', 'breakpoints.theme.armi_embl_theme.mobile');
breakpoints_breakpoint_group_save($new_group);
menu_rebuild();
```

And then finally define the mapping between the image styles and your set of breakpoints:

```
// 3. Add picture mapping
$mapping = picture_mapping_create(TRUE);
$mapping->table = 'picture_mapping';
$mapping->type = 'Normal';
$mapping->export_type = 1;

$mapping->label = 'Tile image mapping';
$mapping->machine_name = 'tile_image_mapping';
$mapping->breakpoint_group = 'tile_image';
$mapping->mapping = array(
  'breakpoints.theme.armi_embl_theme.desktop' => array(
    '1x' => array(
      'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
      'image_style' => 'tile_image_1x',
    ),
  ),
  'breakpoints.theme.armi_embl_theme.mobile' => array(
    '1x' => array(
      'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
      'image_style' => 'tile_image_1x',
    ),
    '1.5x' => array(
      'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
      'image_style' => 'tile_image_1_5x',
    ),
    '2x' => array(
      'mapping_type' => 'image_style',
      'image_style' => 'tile_image_2x',
    ),
  ),
);

picture_mapping_save($mapping);
```